# MultiSelect using Jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [This](http://loudev.com/) Jquery Multi Select but while using it it gives me error for $(...).multiSelect is not a function. I guees it is the problem of javascript not implemented so i check it twice but I found all javascript need is implemented properly. Below is the necessary code for it

```
<div id="PageList" class="portlet-body fuelux" >
 <select name="Pages[]" size="20" id="Pages" multiple="multiple" style="border:none;width:100%"> <option>xyz</option> 
    <option value="1">xyz</option>
    <option value="2">xyz</option> 
    <option value="3">xyz</option> 
    <option value="4">xyz</option>
    <option value="5">xyz</option> 
    <option value="6">xyz</option> 
 </select> 
</div>

<script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/scripts/ui-jqueryui.js"></script>

<script src="~/assets/lou-multi-select-759348a/js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Pages').multiSelect();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you script link is not correct, check it again.

Comment: check the console for the jqery.multi-select.js whether that is added or not?

Comment: check console means you are suggesting console under sources option whether it shows the javascript file or not?

Comment: I check that way but the jqery.multi-select.js was there showing in console under sources tab

Comment: Are there any other javascript errors before "$().multiSelect is not a function"?

Comment: Check you javascript by add a alert.

Comment: No there are no javascript errors before "$().multiSelect is not a function"

Comment: @kirtesh Keep the Scripts above the `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you call the Scripts and I have attached a Screenshot of the o/p:
I have Just moved the Scripts above the HTML

**Note**: its a working example taken from your HTML only

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Pages').multiSelect();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
     <div id="PageList" class="portlet-body fuelux" >
 <select name="Pages[]" size="20" id="Pages" multiple="multiple" style="border:none;width:100%"> <option>xyz</option> 
    <option value="1">xyz</option>
    <option value="2">xyz</option> 
    <option value="3">xyz</option> 
    <option value="4">xyz</option>
    <option value="5">xyz</option> 
    <option value="6">xyz</option> 
 </select> 
</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

**Edit:** After Adding the Css of Multi select here is the view

[image]

Comment: Ok i try as you suggested by creating external html file to test this and its working fine but when i implimented it in my project it stops working so I guess i need to check out on my own what's wrong with my project

Comment: @Kirtesh On which platform you are creating HTML, if its asp.net you can post the design code!!

Comment: I got my problem there is some javascript already exists which was conflicting something as soon as I comment it. It starts working fine